# Laravel 10: Eloquent Relation exists as expected dd( $here ) and {{ $here }}, {{ $but->not->here }}

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I am passing a single `$order` record through to a Blade template, and finding that I cannot access, for example, any order customer attributes, despite them having been included in my query using `with()` and displaying correctly in a blade dump.

I can't seem to put my finger on what I'm doing wrong here to prevent me from accessing `$order->customer->first_name`, for example. Any pointers would be hugely appreciated.

The blade dump of `{{ $order }}` appears like so:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "customer": {
    "id": 20,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  },
  "order_date": "2023-01-10 10:31:51",
  "created_at": "2023-02-11T10:37:05.000000Z",
  ...
}
```

But any attempt to access `$order->customer->first_name` results in this 500 response:
`Attempt to read property "first_name" on int`

`$order->customer` returns the customer id, which makes sense, but is contrary to what the blade dump would suggest should be the case.

A `dd()` on the $order variable before sending it to the blade template gives me this output (shortened)

```
App\Models\Order {#1463 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:139
 ...
  #attributes: array:25 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "customer" => 20
    "rfp" => 69
    "order_date" => "2023-01-10 10:31:51"
    "created_at" => "2023-02-11 23:37:05"
    ...
  ]
  #original: array:25 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:4 [▼
    "rfp" => App\Models\User {#1478 ▶}
    "customer" => App\Models\Customer {#1480 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "customers"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "id" => 20
        "first_name" => "John"
        "last_name" => "Doe"
      ]
      #original: array:3 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: array:1 [▶]
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      +usesUniqueIds: false
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:17 [▶]
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #searchable: array:9 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    ...
  ]
  ...
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/orderpdf/{id}', [OrderController::class, 'generateOrderPDF']);
```

OrderController.php

```
public static function generateOrderPDF($id, Request $request) {

        $select = [
            'customer' => function($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
            }];
            
        $order = Order::with($select)->find($id);
        
        if (!$order) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Order not found.'], 404);
        }

        $pdfHtml = View::make('order-confirmation-pdf', ['order' => $order])->render();

        if ($request->input('preview')) {
            return $pdfHtml;
        }
        
    ...
```

Order.php (Model)

```
public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer');
    }
```

Customer.php (Model)

```
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your orders table has a field called customer that is the same to relationship name in Order model. So when you call $order->customer, it will get the value of this field. In your case, it is 20.

So, you can consider to change the customer field in orders table to customer_id or change the relationship method name in your model:

```
public function customerModel()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer');
}
```

So, then you can access the first name of the customer:

```
$order->customerModel->first_name
```